# Page reload in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a login page which takes the user name and password and directs it to a controller. If the login information is correct, the controller sends some data to be displayed on the home page.

Now, I want to provide a link on the home page that enables the user to refresh the page on a click. This should resubmit the username and password and the page is reloaded, i.e. F5 functionality.
My current code :

```
Please <a href='#' onclick='location.reload(true);'> refresh the page </a>
```

is not exhibiting the form resubmission from the login page. How may I achieve this? Any ideas regarding this would be very helpful.

Comment: Try running `window.location.href = window.location.href;`

Comment: Presumably this is a `POST` form? What about the form inputs? Are they being populated after the initial refresh? Why do you need to submit the data again? Why can't you do whatever it is you need to do with the values the first time round?

Comment: Why do you want to repost the login form?

Comment: Yes, this is a POST form. I need to resubmit the data because the userid helps me to populate a table whose data is fetched from the database.

Comment: Don't you already have the user information in a session. If he is logged in already.

Answer (score 3):

Nice cross-browser support.

**To Reload the page.**

```
window.location.replace(window.location.href);
```

**To submit a form.** Where `<form id="myForm" ... >`.

```
document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
```

**Documentation**
[Replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_replace.asp) / [Href](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp) / [Submit](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp)

Comment: This does not resubmit the login form.

Comment: that depends on if the form is GET or POST

Comment: Submitting a Username and Password I think it's probably POST

Comment: I have a POST form on the login page.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
Please <a href='#' onclick='document.getElementById("myForm").submit();'> refresh the page </a>
```

And just having a hidden form again, if the form is not present any more.

from http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
function reloadPage()
{
location.reload();
}
```

call this function on click of your link

```
onclick="reloadPage()"
```

I think this works .

Answer (score 0):

Try one of  following  -

```
window.location.reload();
history.go(0);
window.location.href=window.location.href;
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try to resend the form with hidden fields?

```html
<form id="formId" action="#">
<input type="hidden" id="user" value="#{userValue}" />
<input type="hidden" id="pass" value="#{passValue}" />
</form>

Please <a href='#' onclick='$("#formId").submit();'> refresh the page </a>
```